# How to insert data from table and pivot it

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014, sql-insert

I have 2 tables.

Table1 has around 2k columns which looks like:

```
Id  A B C D E F G H...........................................AA
1
2
```

Table2 has 2 columns which looks like:

```
Id Category
1  A
1  C
1  AA
2  B 
2  D
```

I want to insert and pivot the data of table2 in table1

Table 1 should finally look like

```
Id  A B C D E F G H...........................................AA
1   1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0...........................................0 
2   0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0...........................................0
```

I am not sure how to do this in sql. Would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What version of SQL, and about how many rows are in Table2?

Comment: Sql Server 2014 - There are around 1M rows in Table2

Comment: And does Table1 really have 2000 columns? That seems like there may be a problem with the design.

Comment: Yes it does. I am using a wide table in SQL. Unfortunately this the requirement

Comment: I would say there is not a probability the design is problematic. There absolutely is a problem in the design. 2000 columns is absurd. You can use the PIVOT operator but man that is going to be brutal with such a crazy amount of columns.

Comment: How many distinct IDs are in Table2? And do you have records that will extend out a couple of thousand columns?

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, I was originally thinking this would be a fairly simple `PIVOT` to `INSERT`, but with that many columns, it might approach the limits of how large the SQL statement can be. I'm not sure how to approach this, but it will be incredibly ugly.

Comment: Wow, I did not realize that in SQL 2017, a Wide Table can have up to   30,000 columns. or that you can have up to 4,096 columns in a `SELECT`!!!

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns?

Comment: Int and Varchar

Comment: Is this a theoretical problem or an actual issue? Because if it's theoretical, I'd probably say to go back to the drawing board and fix the underlying schema issues. If it's an actual problem, then you'll be looking at some non-trivial down time to complete this operation.

Comment: So `Table1.ID` is `int` and all the other columns are `varchar`? And `Table2.ID` is `int` and `Table2.Category` is `varchar`?

Comment: You can use a PIVOT or conditional aggregation. But either way you are going to be writing sql for at least a couple days. I am not kidding. You are going to have to address every single column individually. It isn't terribly complicated but it is terribly repetitive and terrible from a design perspective. I realize this probably isn't your design but it really does need to be addressed because it just isn't maintainable.

Comment: I am trying to use pivot but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: What is the maximum number of columns you will need to PIVOT for this operation? `SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Table2 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY cnt DESC` should get you that number. But if it's a large number, you may be approaching the limits of the SQL you can write in one query, or you may hit memory limits of your server. This really will be a monster of a query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as cnt FROM Table2` should give you the number of rows you'll be working with, if you `PIVOT`.

Comment: People who give "doesn't seem to work" as issues should spend the time end effort to learn how to communicate issues.  Do you get an error?  Then tell us the error!  Do you get results, but not the ones you expected?  Then show us your inputs, your output and the output you actually wanted!  We.Are.Not.Psychic.

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely stupid thing about sql pivot commands is that you have to know/list out every column. For some reason Microsoft Access has a very elegant way of just pivoting everything. Because of this, I wouldn't even bother to use the pivot command. Intead just do massive case and group by

```
select 
id, 
sum(case when category = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as 'A',
sum(case when category = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as 'B',
sum(case when category = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as 'C',
etc...
from table2
group by id
```

I agree with some of the other comments. If your situation allows, consider using Excel PowerQuery which has a great pivot/unpivot command or use a gui-based tool like Alteryx that has a pivot/transpose tools. Much quicker!

Comment: My only question is about whether or not any PIVOT tool will work with the extreme number of columns involved. I'm beginning to think that this may require a non-standard solution that will be extremely slow.

Comment: It looks like the standard limit is 1024 but you can create a type of object known as a "wide column table" which can hold up to 30k. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

One "non-standard" solution would be to break up your pivot into 4 or 5 similar pivots (ie. vertical partition the table) since you have to hard code each column name anyway, it's about the same amount of work. So it would look something like

tbl 1 - id, a, b, c... 
tbl 2 - id, x, y, z....

Then re-join as needed. Sorry char limit

Answer (score 0):

We can use dynamic sql to generate the pivot query with the necessary columns and execute it.

Note: I'm using NULL instead of '0' in missing columns to stay under the allowable maximum sparse data size of 8023 byes.

If the columns a, b, c...AA from the table1 are:

- int: it will support around 800 fields with value 1 and the others null
- bit: it will support around 1142 fields with value 1 and the others null (looking your sample, this is the better datatype)

For check if this script will work, run the next query for check if is less than the fields allow by type.

~~~~

```
SELECT MAX([fields])
FROM (SELECT [fields] = COUNT(DISTINCT [category]) FROM [table2] GROUP BY [id]) AS [t]
```

~~~~

Edited:

- process for batch size of 10000.
- assumes that any id in table2 exists in table1

~~~~

```
DECLARE @target_schema_name SYSNAME = N'dbo'; -- Modify if necessary
DECLARE @target_table_name SYSNAME = N'table1'; -- Modify if necessary
DECLARE @target_table_identifier SYSNAME = N'id'; -- Modify if necessary

DECLARE @source_schema_name SYSNAME = N'dbo'; -- Modify if necessary
DECLARE @source_table_name SYSNAME = N'table2'; -- Modify if necessary
DECLARE @source_table_identifier SYSNAME = N'id'; -- Modify if necessary
DECLARE @source_table_pivoter SYSNAME = N'category'; -- Modify if necessary
DECLARE @source_table_subquery_columns NVARCHAR(MAX) =
    + '[src].' + QUOTENAME(@source_table_identifier)
    + ','
    + '[src].' + QUOTENAME(@source_table_pivoter)
    + ','
    + '[auxiliar] = 1';


DECLARE @columns TABLE([name] SYSNAME);

INSERT INTO @columns ([name])
SELECT [c].[name]
FROM [sys].[schemas] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [sys].[tables] AS [t]
    ON ([s].[schema_id] = [t].[schema_id])
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] AS [c]
    ON ([t].[object_id] = [c].[object_id])
WHERE (1 = 1)
    AND ([s].[name] = @target_schema_name)
    AND ([t].[name] = @target_table_name)
    AND ([c].[name] <> @target_table_identifier)
    AND ([c].[is_column_set] <> 1);

DECLARE @target_table_pivot_columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;
DECLARE @target_table_insert_columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

DECLARE @source_table_insert_columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT
        @target_table_pivot_columns = IIF(@target_table_pivot_columns IS NULL, '', @target_table_pivot_columns + ',') + QUOTENAME([c].[name])
    ,@source_table_insert_columns = IIF(@source_table_insert_columns IS NULL, '', @source_table_insert_columns + ',') + QUOTENAME([c].[name]) --+ ' = ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([c].[name]) + ', 0)'
FROM @columns AS [c];

SET @target_table_insert_columns = QUOTENAME(@target_table_identifier) + ',' + @target_table_pivot_columns;
SET @source_table_insert_columns = QUOTENAME(@source_table_identifier) + ',' + @source_table_insert_columns;

DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @batch_min INT;
DECLARE @batch_max INT;

CREATE TABLE #ids ([id] INT, [batch] INT);

SET @command = '
INSERT INTO #ids ([id], [batch])
SELECT DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(@source_table_identifier) +  ', (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1) / 10000
FROM ' +  QUOTENAME(@source_schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@source_table_name) + ';
';

EXECUTE (@command);

SET @batch_min = 0;
SET @batch_max = (SELECT MAX([batch]) FROM #ids);

WHILE @batch_min <= @batch_max
BEGIN
    SET @command = '
    INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@target_schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@target_table_name) + '(' + @target_table_insert_columns + ')
    SELECT ' + @source_table_insert_columns + '
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ' + @source_table_subquery_columns + '
        FROM ' +  QUOTENAME(@source_schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@source_table_name) + ' AS [src]
        INNER JOIN #ids AS [ids]
            ON ([src].' + QUOTENAME(@source_table_identifier) + ' = [ids].[id])
        WHERE (1 = 1)
            AND ([ids].[batch] = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @batch_min) + ')
    ) AS [src]
    PIVOT (MAX([auxiliar]) FOR [category] IN (' + @target_table_pivot_columns + ')) AS [pvt]
    ';

    EXECUTE (@command);

    SET @batch_min += 1;
END
```

~~~~